# Matrix Approximation and Predicting Timeseries in Python/R with SVD

Tags: python, r, matrix, svd

I have an excel file that is 126 rows and 5 columns full of numbers, I have to use that data and SVD methods to predict 5-10 more rows of data. I have implemented SVD in Python successfully using numpy:

import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

```
my_data = genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')

U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(my_data)

print ("U:")
print (U)
print ("\nSigma:")
print (s)
print ("\nVT:")
print (V)
```

which outputs:

```
U:
[[-0.03339497  0.10018171  0.01013636 ..., -0.10076323 -0.09740801
  -0.08901366]
 [-0.02881809  0.0992715  -0.01239945 ..., -0.02920558 -0.04133748
  -0.06100236]
 [-0.02501102  0.10637736 -0.0528663  ..., -0.0885227  -0.05408083
  -0.01678337]
 ..., 
 [-0.02418483  0.10993637  0.05200962 ...,  0.9734676  -0.01866914
  -0.00870467]
 [-0.02944344  0.10238372  0.02009676 ..., -0.01948701  0.98455034
  -0.00975614]
 [-0.03109401  0.0973963  -0.0279125  ..., -0.01072974 -0.0109425
   0.98929811]]

Sigma:
[ 252943.48015512   74965.29844851   15170.76769244    4357.38062076
    3934.63212778]

VT:
[[-0.16143572 -0.22105626 -0.93558846 -0.14545156 -0.16908786]
 [ 0.5073101   0.40240734 -0.34460639  0.45443181  0.50541365]
 [-0.11561044  0.87141558 -0.07426656 -0.26914744 -0.38641073]
 [ 0.63320943 -0.09361249  0.00794671 -0.75788695  0.12580436]
 [-0.54977724  0.14516905 -0.01849291 -0.35426346  0.74217676]]
```

But I am not sure how to use this data to preidct my values. I am using this link http://datascientistinsights.com/2013/02/17/single-value-decomposition-a-golfers-tutotial/ as a reference but that is in R. At the end they use R to predict values but they use this command in R:

```
approxGolf_1 <- golfSVD$u[,1] %*% t(golfSVD$v[,1]) * golfSVD$d[1]
```

Here is the IdeOne link to the entire R code: http://ideone.com/Yj3y6j

I'm not really familiar with R so can anyone let me know if there is a similar function in Python to the command above or explain what that command is doing exactly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the golf course example data you linked, to set the stage:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.matrix((4,4,3,4,4,3,4,2,5,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,4,5,5,5,2,4,4,4,3,4,5))
A=A.reshape((3,9)).T
```

This gives you the original 9 rows, 3 columns table with scores of 9 holes for 3 players:

```
matrix([[4, 4, 5],
        [4, 5, 5],
        [3, 3, 2],
        [4, 5, 4],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [3, 5, 4],
        [4, 4, 3],
        [2, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5]])
```

Now the singular value decomposition:

```
U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(A)
```

The most important thing to investigate is the vector `s` of singular values:

```
array([ 21.11673273,   2.0140035 ,   1.423864  ])
```

It shows that the first value is much bigger than the  others, indicating that the corresponding [Truncated SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Truncated_SVD) with only one value represents the original matrix `A` quite well. To calculate this representation, you take column 1 of `U` multiplied by the first row of `V`, multiplied by the first singular value. This is what the last cited command in R does. Here is the same in Python:

```
U[:,0]*s[0]*V[0,:]
```

And here is the result of this product:

```
matrix([[ 3.95411864,  4.64939923,  4.34718814],
        [ 4.28153222,  5.03438425,  4.70714912],
        [ 2.42985854,  2.85711772,  2.67140498],
        [ 3.97540054,  4.67442327,  4.37058562],
        [ 3.64798696,  4.28943826,  4.01062464],
        [ 3.69694905,  4.3470097 ,  4.06445393],
        [ 3.34185528,  3.92947728,  3.67406114],
        [ 3.09108399,  3.63461111,  3.39836128],
        [ 4.5599837 ,  5.36179782,  5.0132808 ]])
```

Concerning the vector factors `U[:,0]` and `V[0,:]`: Figuratively speaking, `U` can be seen as a representation of a hole's difficulty, while `V` encodes a player's strength.

Comment: Wow you are a genius, thanks! You explained it very well. I just have one comment, when I use it on my data, which is a 126x5 matrix, I get this error: predictions = U[:,0]*s[0]*V[0,:]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (126) (5). I am using the SVD values from my post above

Comment: When I use the golf course data everything works fine though, do you know why my data above shows ..., in the U determination? Here is the data I am using: http://pastebin.com/YYAM35Pd. How are you supposed to control how many values it predicts? For my case will it predict 126x5 rows of more data? Sorry for the ton of questions, I can barely find anything about SVD that isn't over my head online.

Comment: I have not spoken of *prediction* yet in my answer, just how SVD helps to represent characteristics of data with less data, i.e. the vectors corresponding to the largest singular values. Please ask another question specifically about the prediction issue. In a nutshell, you need to know `U` for new instances (the golf course difficulties) so that you can use `V` (player skill) to predict a score.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Do you know why I am receiving the error above however?

Comment: Are you sure that you use a numpy _matrix_, not an _array_? If `U` and `V` are arrays, you have to use the `dot` function for matrix multiplication, while the `*` operator might fail with the message you provided.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I converted them to matrices using np.matrix and then used np.multiply